# ListView cannot scroll

Tags: android, android-listview

I have tried to scroll the ListView up when the event item is more than the space of the ListView but it fails. I would like to know if I can make the ListView scrollable without adding any listener. Thank you.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context="com.example.ssycorpapp.SecondActivity" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/events"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

               <SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/search"
                    android:queryHint="@string/hint"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </SearchView>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/titleBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/search" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/resultName"
                        android:layout_width="180dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:text="@string/event"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/resultDate"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/resultTime"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/resultTime"
                        android:text="@string/eventDate"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@id/resultTime"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:text="@string/eventTime"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/event_list"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/titleBar"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/DelAll" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/DelAll"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:text="@string/DelAll" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/set"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/EventName"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/event" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/eveName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:inputType="text" >
                    </EditText>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/EventDate"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/eventDate" />

                    <DatePicker
                        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="158dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/EventTime"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/eventTime" />

                    <TimePicker
                        android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="109dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Tim"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/Set" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Don't use ListView and ScrollView at once

Comment: @Nabin Even if ListView and ScrollView is in different tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use any listener then you can simply use a custom ListView like this,

```
public class CustomListView extends ListView implements View.OnTouchListener, AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

    private static final int MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE = 99;
    private int listViewTouchAction;

    public CustomListView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        listViewTouchAction = -1;
        setOnScrollListener(this);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (getAdapter() != null && getAdapter().getCount() > MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE) {
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                scrollBy(0, -1);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int newHeight = 0;
        final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = getAdapter();
            if (listAdapter != null && !listAdapter.isEmpty()) {
                int listPosition = 0;
                for (listPosition = 0; listPosition < listAdapter.getCount()
                        && listPosition < MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE; listPosition++) {
                    View listItem = listAdapter.getView(listPosition, null, this);
                    //now it will not throw a NPE if listItem is a ViewGroup instance
                    if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup) {
                        listItem.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    }
                    listItem.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
                    newHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
                }
                newHeight += getDividerHeight() * listPosition;
            }
            if ((heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) && (newHeight > heightSize)) {
                if (newHeight > heightSize) {
                    newHeight = heightSize;
                }
            }
        } else {
            newHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), newHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (getAdapter() != null && getAdapter().getCount() > MAXIMUM_LIST_ITEMS_VIEWABLE) {
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                scrollBy(0, 1);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then use in your layout,

```
 <CustomListView 
  android:id="@+id/event_list"
  android:scrollbars="vertical"
  android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
  android:layout_below="@id/titleBar"
  android:layout_above="@+id/DelAll" />
```

Comment: Thank you. But is there any solution that I can just add or edit something in the .xml file?

Comment: I guess no. If you use a ListView inside a ScrollView there's no other way to prevent this just by using a xml tag.

Comment: But ListView is outside the ScrollView and they are seperated in different tabs

Comment: Yes! but if you don't handle the touch events manually the ListView and ScrollView are going to be conflicted. I can't give you the valid reason but it simply doesn't works.